# How to improve Image Scraping (using PHP and JS) to Imitate Facebook Previewer

Tags: php, javascript, image-processing, web-scraping

I've developed an **image-scraping mechanism in PHP+JS** that allows a user to share URLs and get a rendered preview (very much like Facebook's previewer when you share links). However, the whole process sometimes gets slow or sometimes fetches wrong images, so in general, **I'd like to know how to improve it, especially its speed and accuracy**. Stuff like parsing the DOM faster or getting image sizes faster. Here's the process I'm using, for those who want to know more:

A. Get the HTML of the page using PHP (I actually use one of [CakePHP's classes](http://api12.cakephp.org/class/http-socket), which in turn use `fwrite` and `fread` to fetch the HTML. I wonder if cURL would be significantly better).

B. Parse the HTML using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the img tags, while also filtering out any "image" that is not a png, jpg, or gif (you know, sometimes people place tracking scripts inside img tags).

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();  
@$DOM->loadHTML($html); //$html here is a string returned from step A  
$images = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');  
$imagesSRCs = array();  
foreach ($images as $image) {  
    $src = trim($image->getAttribute('src'));  
    if (!preg_match('/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/', $src)) {  
        continue;  
    }  
    $src = urldecode($src);  
    $src = url_to_absolute($url, $src); //custom function; $url is the link shared  
    $imagesSRCs[] = $src;  
}  
$imagesSRCs = array_unique($imagesSRCs); // eliminates copies of a same image
```

C. Send an array with all those image tags to a page which processes using Javascript (specifically, JQuery). This processing consists mostly in discarding images that are less than 80pixels (so I dont get blank gifs, hundreds of tiny icons, etc.). Because it must calculate each image size, I decided to use JS instead of PHP's `getimagesize()` because it was insanely slow. Thus, as the images get loaded by the browser, it does the following:

```
$('.fetchedThumb').load(function() {  
    $smallestDim = Math.min(this.width, this.height);  
    if ($smallestDim < 80) {  
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //removes container divs and below  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Do you know what is the real bottleneck in your setup? My guess would be the downloading of all the images, but I might be wrong. Some profiling tools such as Firebug and Opera Dragonfly can tell you how long the downloading takes. And why not go all javascript on this (the browser's dom parsers are really good and fast) and let the client do all the downloading, offloading the server.

Comment: Yeah, Rodin. I'm also sure that the bottleneck is the image loading. But as far as I know, the browser needs to load _each_ image before knowing its dimensions, which leave me with no alternative except for "loading --> inspect --> discard or leave). Of course, I can always get dimensions from server-side, but that proved to be 10x worse.
Also, will consider using JS for parsing the DOM instead of DOMDocument. Thanks.
Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading the content like this, why not create a server-side component that uses something like wkhtmltoimage or PhantomJS to render an image of the page, and then just scale the image down to a preview size.

Comment: Thanks for showing me what is PhantomJS, but I don't think a whole 'screenshot' of the shared website would be good, because that screenshot is then resized to 80px (the specified thumb size) and it would be too small to really notice any details.

What the App manager wants to have is the Facebook 'Previewer' and that's it. And while I got most of it done, I want to improve its speed and accuracy (and I already received some ideas for it). True, even the Facebook Previewer sometimes fails and output a bunch of wrong images (blank, small icons, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why I made [jQueryScrape](http://brianzeligson.com/jqueryScrape/)

It's a very lightweight jQuery plugin + PHP proxy that lets you scrape remote pages asynchronously, and it's blazing fast. That demo I linked above goes to around 8 different sites and pulls in tons of content, usually in less than 2 seconds.

The biggest bottleneck when scraping with PHP is that PHP will try to download all referenced content (meaning images) as soon as you try to parse anything server side. To avoid this, the proxy in jQueryScrape actually breaks image tags on the server before sending it to the client (by changing all img tags to span tags.)

The jQuery plugin then provides a span2img method that converts those span tags back to images, so the downloading of images is left to the browser and happens as the content is rendered. You can at that point use the result as a normal jQuery object for parsing and rendering selections of the remote content. See the [github](https://github.com/beezee/jqueryScrape) page for basic usage.

Comment: Wow. Sounds promising. Im going to take a look later and decide if that suits my needs. Thanks.